# Java Web Service using Jersey JAX-RS

Tags: java

I have web service class which when called by HTML login page return the username that is search as follows:

```java
package com.paybyphone.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.paybyphone.model.MyDatabase;

@Path("/WebService")
public class LoginService {

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public String login(@FormParam("userName") String userName) {
        return getAllUsersList(userName.trim());
    }

    public String getAllUsersList(String userName) {
        try {
            // MyDatabase.createRegTable();
            // MyDatabase.insertRecords();
            MyDatabase rd = new MyDatabase();
            List<UserVO> userList = null;
            userList = MyDatabase.SelectAllRecords();
            for (UserVO userVO : userList) {

                String name = userVO.getUserName().trim();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(userName)) {
                    return "Logged in User:" + userName;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        return "You are not a Valid User";
    }
}
```

Please! can some one help me on how to redirect to another HTML page if username is found, instead of returning it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a String from your method, return a javax.ws.rs.core.Response. The Response class uses a builder pattern, so you can:

```
if (loginCheckingMethod(login)) {
    return Response.seeOther(uri).build();
}
```

Comment: where can I defined login and uri?

Comment: Those were just for example; looks like you actually called the login variable userName; 'uri' is a value you'd have to construct to be a valid argument for seeOther().

Comment: Please! Can you help with an example of how shall I do it using my login method. Sorry I am new into java web service.

Answer (score 0):

In the *worst* case you can write by hand a HTML page and change the method "signature" 
to

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
```

If I were you, I'd use JSP/JSF based web frameworks for this end. 
As a side note, Jersey supports JSP off the shelf via `Viewable` class [Jersey & viewable](http://www.lucubratory.eu/simple-jerseyrest-and-jsp-based-web-application/)